# Read a generic List<T> with parent/child hierarchy into a datatable preserving the parent/child hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, tree, parent-child

I have transformed this XML tree with the names of the units:
Dim = Dimension

```
Dim1            
|---MG1     
    |---M1  
    |---M2  
    |---M3  
        |---MG31
        |---MG32


Dim2            
|---MG220       
    |---MG2222
```

...into a List of Units aka List where every Unit can have another List with unlimited hierarchy. Now I want to transform the List to a tabular format with the parent/child hierarchy.

That way should the datatable look like:

```
Dimension...Parent..Child
Dim1........Dim1....MG1
Dim1........MG1.....M1
Dim1........MG1.....M2
Dim1........Dim1....MG2
Dim1........MG1.....M3
Dim1........M3......MG31
Dim1........M3......MG32
Dim2........Dim2....MG220
Dim2........MG220...MG2222

public class Unit           
{           
   public String Name { get; set; }         
   public Unit Dimension { get; set; }          
   public UnitParent { get; set; }          
   public List<Unit> Children { get; set; }         

}
```

Question: How would you iterate the List and write all the data into a DataTable ?
There must be a tricky algoryth I can not find.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is the right approach here, but I'm going to suggest a LINQ approach - especially as this question was tagged with LINQ.

One of the nice things with LINQ is that extension methods can take away a lot of complexity and leave simple queries that express the business logic simply.

So here's what I use to flatten recursive structures:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> @this, T root)
{
    var head = new [] { root, };
    var tail =
        from c in @this(root)
        where !c.Equals(root)
        from d in @this.Flatten(c)
        select d;
    return head.Concat(tail);
}
```

Note the recursive call to `Flatten` and that this is an extension method defined on the function that returns the children from a given parent item.

Now we can define the `Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>` like this:

```
Func<Unit, IEnumerable<Unit>> f = u => u.Children;
```

And then, assuming that all `Dimension`, `Parent`, and `Children` properties are not null, we can use this query to produce the list of records to add to the table:

```
var records =
    from r in dimensions
    from d in f.Flatten(r)
    select new
    {
        Dimension = d.Dimension.Name,
        Parent = d.Parent.Name,
        d.Name,
    };
```

Now, if any of the properties are `null`, here's the fix.

Redefine `f` as:

```
Func<Unit, IEnumerable<Unit>> f = u => u.Children ?? new List<Unit>();
```

And add this extension method:

```
public static R ValueOrNull<T, R>(this T @this, Func<T, R> selector)
    where R : class
{
    return @this != null ? selector(@this) : null;
}
```

Now the query works like this:

```
var records =
    from r in dimensions
    from d in f.Flatten(r)
    select new
    {
        Dimension = d.Dimension.ValueOrNull(x => x.Name),
        Parent = d.Parent.ValueOrNull(x => x.Name),
        d.Name,
    };
```

Still very similar, but `null` safe.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. I gave you a point for the good snippet I can surely use another day. Not a solution because I realized the existing code structure is different than I thought/expected therefore it needs another solution which was quite easy :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive algorithm will do fine...

```
function AddSubTree(Unit unit) {
  if (unit != unit.Dimension)
    AddItemToDataTable(unit.Dimension.Name, unit.UnitParent.Name, unit.Name);
  foreach (Unit childUnit in unit.Children) {
    AddSubTree(childUnit); 
  }
}
```

you call `AddSubTree` for every dimension object you have

Comment: does not work. The unit passed to AddSubTree is often null throwing exception. Actually a dimension should not be null... I guess that cant be solved without throwing all source code here... sorry Variant, but thx for help. I have to play now...